# OpenVPN: Pushed DHCP & DNS options not working on Windows client

Tags: windows, networking, debian, vpn, openvpn

I am running OpenVPN 2.4 on a RaspberryPi with OS  Raspbian Stretch (Debian).
My client machine runs Windows 10 Home. Running OpenVPN GUI (with admin privileges).
My OpenVPN server conf file is meant to push my local DNS IP but is not working:

```
tls-server
local 192.168.1.70
port 1194
dev tun
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
proto udp4
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth-nocache
persist-key
persist-tun
ncp-disable
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1"
# Key & cert files lines are below here
```

My Windows client OVPN file:

```
tls-client
remote myDomain.com 1194
topology subnet
dev tun
dev-node OpenVPN
dev-type tun
ifconfig 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0
proto udp4
cipher AES-256-GCM
ncp-disable
remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Server Authentication"
# Key & cert files lines are below here
```

My client log file shows:

```
Thu Jul 04 22:40:36 2019 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.8.0.2/255.255.255.0 on interface {7960DABA-08FA-46FF-B8B2-A57ACDAB8247} [DHCP-serv: 10.8.0.254, lease-time: 31536000]
```

The problem shows in my IPCONFIG /all:

```
Ethernet adapter OpenVPN:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-79-60-DC-EB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4d93:4f27:6a9f:9314%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 04 July 2019 22:40:36
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 03 July 2020 22:40:35
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 788594553
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-2A-20-42-70-8B-CD-17-C3-0C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Notice that the TAP adaptor has not been set a DNS IPV4 IP address (i.e. should be 192.168.1.1).
Although some miscellaneous IPV6 DNS entries are set (not sure where these are coming from).
If I set the DNS in the client's ovpn file then it works correctly (dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1).
I have also not been able to push Default Gateway, but trying to resolve one problem at a time!
Any help appreciated.
Nigel